# Wrote a Macro Search that needs approximate match instead of exact

Tags: vba, excel, search

I wrote a macro to search through a filter for an exact match in column A and it needs an approximate match for a search in column B. Right now I only have it as an exact match, and I need help making it an approximate match code.  Below is my code:

```
Sub SearchBox1()

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim MyVal As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

'Load Sheet into A Variable
 Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
 On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
 On Error GoTo 0

 'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A50:$L$130").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sht.Shapes("CountrySearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In this instance you may need Criteria1:="*" & sht.Shapes("CountrySearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text & "*"

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an approximate match?

Comment: It depends on the type of match you want:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491148/best-fuzzy-matching-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Criteria1 to this

if it's searching for a string:

> Criteria1:= **"*" &** sht.Shapes("CountrySearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text **& "*"**

or, if you have numbers

> Criteria1:= **">="** & sht.Shapes("CountrySearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text